# Python Selenium Webdriver: AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a trouble with the select element when I try to run my code it gives me an error

```
AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

like I don't have any select element. Is it because it is not focusing on popup? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

MyCode.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.punjnud.com/PageList.aspx?BookID=14050&BookTitle=Ali%20Zaryoun%20Ki%20Ghazalein")

popupSelect=Select(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("(//select[@class='custom-dropdown selectdrop'])[1]"))

popupSelect.select_by_value("1")

browser.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-success").click()
```

Error in select.py:

```
if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
    raise UnexpectedTagNameException("Select only works on <select> elements, not on <%s>" %webelement.tag_name)
```

Exception:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

Comment: How are you initializing `webelement` variable?

Comment: I am find element by xpath and storing it popupSelect variable in MyCode.py

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`find_elements_by_xpath` returns list of WebElements.

It should be `find_element_by_xpath`. Note the `s` in `find_element`.

Comment: Thanks for answering

Comment: Hi @M Talha Afzal I have the same problem but your suggestion doen't work. Can you help me on this issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362476/python-selenium-unable-to-select-drop-down-menu