# Extract data using find_elements_by_class_name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract each **class_name='position-header'** on the page by using find_elements_by_class_name but when I do so I receive the error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

```
from parsel import Selector  
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys   

employment = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('position-header')
```

The screenshot shows that it returns data when the method **find_element_by_class_name** is used but when using **find_elements_by_class_name** I encounter the error.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium Webdriver: AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'tag\_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052303/python-selenium-webdriver-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-tag-na)

Comment: The first thing you should do when you run into an error that you don't know how to correct is to google it, `python selenium 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`. If you would have done so, you would have found a LOT of existing questions, blogs, etc. that address this issue with solutions.

Comment: That does not answer the question @JeffC

Comment: @vortal It's the exact same problem. If you read the answers on the question I linked, you would understand the problem and be able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The `driver.find_elements_by_class_name()` method returns a list of matching elements, and you are trying to access the `text` attribute on the list, which doesn't exist... `text` is only available on a *single instance* of element.

You would either have select the first one and access the `.text` attribute:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('position-header')[0].text
```

or iterate over the list and get the ext of each element:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('position-header')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Comment: This should nail the OP